# Reconciling a tree view with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing a tree view in React.  The tree view has a drag and drop ability where a node can be moved around and between parents.

With that in mind, when React reconciles my component tree from:

```xml
<TreeNode key="item1">
    <TreeNode key="item2"/>
    <TreeNode key="item3"/>
    <TreeNode key="item4"/>
</TreeNode>
```

To something like this:

```xml
<TreeNode key="item1">
    <TreeNode key="item2"/>
    <TreeNode key="item3"/>
</TreeNode>
<TreeNode key="item4"/>
```

Will it preserve `item4` (i.e. not unmount and remount it)?  Is there some way I can force it to keep that component intact while moving it to a new parent or does React only consider `key`s when it's reconciling siblings?

Comment: I'm specifically wondering about the selection on a `<textarea>` in the component.

Answer (score 1):

First, just a clarification - React elements are not supposed to be "preserved" - it is the underlying DOM element that will be "preserved".

React will try to reuse the DOM when it is possible to do so.

The key property determines what happens with the DOM element. Whenever key exists in a subsequent render pass, the DOM will be reused and content updated.

Quoting from
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

> When children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the
>   original tree with children in the subsequent tree.